# Why am I my losing my <textarea> data in the $_POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am writing a script that will take some form data and present it in a PDF or some other printable format. At the bottom of the form is a "New Line" button. When you click this button a new line in the form appears, and the data in the previous line is added to an array named according to its label tag. My problem is that when the form is submitted the only data that ends up in the $desc[] array is what ever was entered in the last row. can someone please look over my code and see what I may have done wrong?

```
if (isset($_POST['new_line']) || isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Grab POST data
    $invoice_quote = trim($_POST['invoice_quote']);
    $sales_person = trim($_POST['sales_person']);
    $job = trim($_POST['job']);
    $due_date = trim($_POST['due_date']);
    $first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
    $address = trim($_POST['address']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    $state = trim($_POST['state']);
    $zip = trim($_POST['zip']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $qty = array_filter(array_map('trim', $_POST['qty']));
    $desc = array_filter(array_map('trim', $_POST['desc']));
    $unit_price = array_filter(array_map('trim', $_POST['unit_price']));
    $line_total = array_filter(array_map('trim', $_POST['line_total']));
    $line = trim($_POST['line']);



    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $flag = 'FALSE';

        // This is only for test proposes, This is untimately where the 
        // code will go that will generate the PDF
        echo ('<div class= "info">'.$invoice_quote.' '.$sales_person.' '.$job.' '.$due_date.' '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' '.$address.' '.$city.' '.$state.' '.$zip.' '.$phone.' '.$email.'<br />');
        var_dump($qty);
        echo '<br />';
        var_dump($desc);
        echo '<br />';
        var_dump($unit_price);
        echo '<br />';
        var_dump($line_total);
        echo('</div>');
        exit();

      }

}

<form id="invoiceform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<fieldset class= "description">
                            <label for= "qty" class= "qty">Qty</label>
                            <label for= "desc" class= "desc">Description</label>
                            <label for= "unit_price" class= "unit_price">Unit Price</label>
                            <label for= "line_total" class= "line_total">Line Total</label>
                            <br/>
                    <?php
                        if ($flag == 'TRUE') {
                            $n = 0;
                            do {
                    ?>
                                <input type= "text" class= "qtyinfo" name= "qty[]" maxlength "10" value= "<?php if (isset($qty[$n])) echo ($qty[$n]); ?>"/>
                                <textarea class= "descinfo" name= "desc[]" id="<?php echo('desc_'.$n); ?>" value= "<?php if (isset($desc[$n])) echo ($desc[$n]); ?>"></textarea>
                                <input type= "text" class= "unit_priceinfo" name= "unit_price[]" id="<?php echo('unit_price_'.$n); ?>" maxlength= "10" value= "<?php if (isset($unit_price[$n])) echo ($unit_price[$n]); ?>" />
                                <input type= "text" class= "line_totalinfo" name= "line_total[]" id= "<?php echo('line_total_'.$n); ?>" maxlength= "10" value= "<?php if (isset($line_total[$n])) echo ($line_total[$n]); ?>" />
                                <br/>
                    <?php
                                $n++;
                            }
                            while ($n < $line);
                        }
                    ?>



                <input type= "hidden" id= "line" name= "line" value= "<?php echo $line + 1; ?>"/>
                <input type= "submit" id= "new_line" name= "new_line" value= "New Line" />
            </fieldset><br />
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code you provided us. Include the form tag, relevant form element(s) and code relevant to accessing the data once it is posted. Everything else is irrelevant (for now).

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show you?

Comment: Wheres the actual code for the button you speak of? And the code that adds a "new line"?

Comment: I have made some changes to this code that PeterVR suggested. These changes cleaned up my code a bit but the problem still persists. I have also cleaned up my post. I have taken out all the irrelevant parts of my script. j08691, you asked where the "New Line" button was? It is the last input type="submit" in this post. andrewsi, the var_dump() shows a blank string for all previous elements in the $desc[] array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
<textarea id= "desc" name=  "<?php echo('desc_'.$n); ?>"><?php if (isset($desc[$n])) echo ($desc[$n]); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I was giving my textarea tag a value attribute. It took me a while to realize what you were telling me to do but I got. Some times I'm a little thick headed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are adding multiple fields with the same id. Inside your loop you have this:

```
<input type= "text" id= "qty" name= "<?php echo('qty_'.$n); ?>" maxlength "10" value= "<?php if (isset($qty[$n])) echo ($qty[$n]); ?>"/>
<textarea id= "desc" name=  "<?php echo('desc_'.$n); ?>" value= "<?php if (isset($desc[$n])) echo ($desc[$n]); ?>"></textarea>
<input type= "text" id= "unit_price" name=  "<?php echo('unit_price_'.$n); ?>" maxlength= "10" value= "<?php if (isset($unit_price[$n])) echo ($unit_price[$n]); ?>" />
<input type= "text" id= "line_total" name=  "<?php echo('line_total_'.$n); ?>" maxlength= "10" value= "<?php if (isset($line_total[$n])) echo ($line_total[$n]); ?>" />
```

This produces multiple instances of the same id when the loop is ran more then once, wich is invalid html and could explain the issues you are having. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
    <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="<?php echo('qty_'.$n); ?>" maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset($qty[$n])) echo ($qty[$n]); ?>"/>
    <textarea name="desc[]" id="<?php echo('desc_'.$n); ?>" value="<?php if (isset($desc[$n])) echo ($desc[$n]); ?>"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="unit_price[]" id="<?php echo('unit_price_'.$n); ?>" maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset($unit_price[$n])) echo ($unit_price[$n]); ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="line_total[]" id= "<?php echo('line_total_'.$n); ?>" maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset($line_total[$n])) echo ($line_total[$n]); ?>" />
```

As you will notice i swapped the names and id's. Multiple names is allowed. Even more, if you add the square braces as i did, the fields with the same name will be returned as an array, wich makes processing them in the backend very easy.